# IntelliJ is it possible to add @Overrides to all methods of a particular interface?

Tags: java, annotations, intellij-idea

I have created an interface, with about 30 methods and implemented in 30 classes.

I want to add @Override to each of the implementations, but i would like not to do it by hand.

How can IntelliJ help me?

interface looks like this:

```
public interface PreviewObjectTests {
    void testGetName();
    void testGetType();
    //... 30 similar methods
}
```

implementation code:

```
public class PreviewObjectAccountTest implements PreviewObjectTests {

    //I want to add @Override here!
    @Test public void testGetName() {
        assertThat(...);
    }

    //I want to add @Override here!
    @Test public void testGetType() {
        assertThat(...);
    }

    //...30 similar methods 

}
```

Comment: easy to do in eclipse, don't know about intellij.

Comment: How would you do it in Eclipse, then? It could be helpful for readers of this question to know :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Easily done with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> intention, then press **Right arrow** for the sub-menu:

[image: Fix all]

Comment: Actually i am not getting this intention suggestion in my file.  Only intention i have on my list is `Expand to '@test()'`. Does the intention you refer to only work in production class files, and not in tests?

Comment: Make sure project language level is set to 1.6 or higher.

Comment: Language level *is set* to `"level 6.0 - @Override in interfaces"`. (I use intelliJ 11.01 with java 1.6.0_27).

Comment: Do you have the Missing @Override annotation inspection enabled in Settings | Inspections? Do you get method name highlighted like on my screenshot? Press Alt+Enter while the caret is on the highlighted code. I've verified that it works for test classes as well. Can you share a sample project so that we can try to reproduce the problem with the missing intention action?

Comment: The @Override annotation was missing for me

Comment: Make sure the method name is in focus/selected when pressing Alt + Enter.

Answer (score 55):

For IntelliJ:

1. Check if you have "Missing @Override annotation" checked inside Preferences -> Project Settings -> Inspections -> Inheritance issues.
2. Use Analyze -> Inspect Code
3. Find Inheritance issues -> Missing @Override annotation inside "Results for Inspection Profile" window.
4. Apply fix "Add @Override annotation"
   [image: Apply fix "Add @Override annotation"]

Comment: Its in "Class Structure" instead of "Inheritance issues" in my version of Intellij but you can search on that "inspections" screen for "override" and find the "Missing @Overrid annotation" easily.

Answer (score -3):

I found a way to do it with the simple find/replace tool.

1. First i changed a method name to provoke all files implementing the interface to change
2. Then i created a simple find/replace to look only in changed files.

[image: Intellij Add @override for tests in changed files only]

This works in my particular case, because there were not really any other methods in the class files. I will assume this will be a bit more crazy if i had a lot of methods in the files belonging to other interfaces

Comment: -1 (which I cant do :)) Doing search / replace for this is a bad idea.

Comment: I agree that it is a bad idea, but no better ideas have come up. Fortunately, this worked for me because of the way i organized my unit test files.

Comment: Text replace is not good, because you need to check which methods are actually overriding, and which are not. And since this feature is built-in in the Java IDEs, I have no option but to down vote :'(

Answer (score -3):

Its not eclipse or idea specfic. Its compiler specfic and what compliance you adhere to. 
In eclipse its 1.6 or higher.
And In idea I believe its for 1.5 or higher.

In the above cases it will bechecked automatically by respective IDEs.

Comment: Sorry mate for the negative. The question is about automatic fixing: "I want to add @Override to each of the implementations, but i would like not to do it by hand."

Answer (score -3):

For Eclipse (tested on Mars.2):

Window / Preferences (or Project Properties)
  Java / Compiler
    Error/Warnings
      Annotations
        Missing @Override annotation - Set to Error (or Warning)

After the rebuild workspace, in the Markers view, right click on one of the errors, Quick Fix (Ctrl+1) and all the errors should appear. Select all and apply the fix.

This worked for me to properly annotate a few hundreds of classes...